# Why is this C# timer code not working?

Tags: c#, timer

I need to be able to disable a button for 1.5 seconds at a time for an application I'm writing.  An image is displayed, a user clicks a button, and then another image is displayed.  I need to make sure that the user doesn't click the button again too quickly.

So, when the image is displayed, I call this function:

```
    //when a new image is displayed, start the timer and disable the 'done' button
    //for 1.5 seconds, to force people to stop pressing next so quickly
    System.Timers.Timer mTimer;
    void TimerStart() {
        Done.IsEnabled = false;

        mTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        mTimer.Interval = 1500;
        mTimer.Start();
        mTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEnd);
    }
```

The TimerEnd code looks like:

```
    void TimerEnd(object sender, EventArgs eArgs) {
        if (sender == mTimer){
            Done.IsEnabled = true;
            mTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

The 'Done.IsEnabled' line gets hit, but the button is not reenabled and the timer doesn't stop firing.  What am I doing wrong here?  If it matters, this is a WPF app.

Comment: I don't see any code in the TimerEnd method that would enable the button again

Comment: Aside from the approach being good or bad, for good measure in your example, you should add the event handler (Elapsed += ...) BEFORE you enable the event to fire (Start()).

Comment: @Ed-- that's the Done.IsEnabled call.  @Jason- good point, I'll swap it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use DispatcherTimer instead

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(someInterval);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(someEventHandler);
timer.Start();

private void someEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
//some operations
//if you want this event handler executed for just once
// DispatcherTimer thisTimer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
// thisTimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are trying to debounce the button, to prevent too quick clicks. Rather than use a timer save the previous click time in millis, if the button is clicked again within a short time ignore the next event.

Comment: An interesting idea, and certainly a reasonable solution as well.

Comment: It's not that you want to ignore the event, because you won't know whether it is the final event until the interval is passed, and then you may want to act on that event. You need the timer ! See the definition of 'debounce' here: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#LC555

Answer (score 1):

The timer event is raised on a different thread.  When working with the winforms controls, you need to make sure you `Invoke` them from the same thread where they were called.

Answer (score 0):

When working with WPF there is no guarantee that updates made to UI controls on non-UI threads will work as expected. In many cases you will get an exception when you do this.

In your Timer elapsed handler you need to use the BeginInvoke/EndInvoke paradigm and put your button enabling logic in there to ensure that this code runs on the UI thread instead of Begin/End Invoke

There is a SynchnornizationContext available as well which can be accessed by calling `SynchronizationContext.Current` . You'll need to cache this before you make the timer call since SynchronizationContext.Current will be null in non-UI threads.

[This](http://wildermuth.com/2009/04/12/For_Now_Don_t_Use_SynchronizationContext_in_Silverlight_2_or_3) link talks about this as well.

Comment: Regardless. The Begin/Invoke part still applies. The WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send doesn't apply. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @Abhijeet-- maybe, but when I use the timer code in the accepted answer without invoking or using any other threading code, it works.  Therefore, I think your answer is either wrong, or doesn't apply.

Comment: @MMR:The accepted solution is definitely the right approach when using timers.That said the DispatcherTimer handles the routing of work to UI thread(such as when updating controls).If you were to use child threads (which a regular Timer does implicitly) as you have you would still be responsible for performing the marshaling yourself.
Check out "Using the Dispatcher" section on MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S3
Also check out 
http://code.dortikum.net/2008/08/06/timer-vs-dispatchertimer-in-wpf/

I would do my homework before pointing out that an answer is wrong!